# protobuf c++ generate Message instead of MessageLite

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have some proto definitions that i want to compile to C++ headers/code. When i do, all the data types are `MessageLite`, which I understand is more light weight for resource constraint devices.

However, `MessageLite` is missing a bunch of functions that i need (eg: `MessageToJsonString` and `SerializeToOsStream`). Is there a way for `protoc` to generate `Message` instead of `MessageLite`?

Alternatively, is there a better way to work with `MessageLite`? Namely, debugging and serializing to file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in your protobuf definition for the following line:

`option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;`

and either comment it out, or remove it.  That line is instructing protoc to use MessageLite, not Message.

Comment: is there a better way to work using MessageLite? It doesnt even implement SerializeToOsStream. how would i serialize the message to be saved to disk? serializeasString? somehow i feel that's less efficient

Comment: Look at the [ParseFromZeroCopyStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite.ParseFromZeroCopyStream.details) method and the various subclasses of [ZeroCopyInputStream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream#ZeroCopyInputStream)